# MVC Routing - Reroute Specific URI to Another URI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

We have a few links showing up in Google Places that have an incorrect/old format. Those are being fixed on the Google Places side. Until those changes propagate, I am trying to put a band aid on it and redirect the broken URIs to good ones.

I need to reroute two URIs:
1. http://www.BusinessName/Locations/Location?name=Vegas and 2. http://www.BusinessName/Locations/Vegas 
and send them to a single, working URI, 
 http://www.BusinessName/Locations/Location?name=**Las**Vegas (note the different name)

Back in the ASP days I would have just done a response.redirect, but I know that is a no no in MVC.

My RouteConfig.cs default routing is below and pretty standard. The {name} parameter is the location.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "LocationDetail",
            "Locations/{name}",
            new { controller = "Location", action = "Location" });
```

The LocationController will also handle the format, http://www.BusinessName/Locations/Location?name=Vegas.

I fully get how I could change the route formats to something a different order like {controller}, {id}, {action} and I've built a few routes to go to some static content, but nothing I have tried has worked with simply rerouting "http://www.BusinessName/Locations/Location?name=Vegas" to "http://www.BusinessName/Locations/Location?name=**Las**Vegas"

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is `Return RedirectToAction(...)` inside your controller.

Comment: @JohnieKarr - this was simple and worked for me. Add as an answer and I will accept. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `Return RedirectToAction(...)` inside your controller.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is at the IIS level. Install the [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) if you don't have it already, and then you can set up a permanent redirect from these two URLs to the correct one. Then, IIS will redirect automatically, and your application doesn't have to get involved or care.

Comment: I gave this a try and I could see it being useful for something a bit more complex than what I am trying to deal with.